# COBOL programs connecting to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, connections

Has anyone successfully made a connection to SQL Server using a COBOL program? Hoping to make a connection so that hundreds of COBOL programs don't need to be rewritten.

Answer (score 4):

We use [Microfocus](https://www.microfocus.com/) to emulate the z/os (and DB2) environment on the Windows platform - we have a couple thousand Cobol programs successfully accessing Sql Server daily to run our entire legacy system.  It's not cheap though.

Answer (score 1):

There should also be ODBC version for COBOL in the download

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

A few years ago I worked with a SQL Server 2000/2005 based datawarehouse that was fed from COBOL on UNIX (sorry not sure what versions/platforms exactly). We used an ODBC driver from Transoft called U/SQL and called into it from scripting within DTS (well it was a few years ago!)  So I know we could pull data from COBOL into SQL, not sure if it works the other way?

This I believe is now owned by Advanced Computer Software : https://www.oneadvanced.com/products/usql/